# Sails.js app for multiple domains

Tags: express, nginx, sails.js

Is there a way to handle multiple domains with the same Sails.js app, each one with their own configuration - like db and theme - but using the same code?

Eg:

mySailsAapp listen on port 80 and both the domains (client-domain.com
and client2-domain.com) point to this server. Both of the websites run through the same app, but accessing different databases and rendering different themes.

I'm used to do this with pure Express.js and the vhost npm module, but I'd like do this with Sails.js.